# Multi level array assignment

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the example PHP array representation

```
array(
 "test1" => array(
             "test1subtest1" => array(..)
            ),
 "test2" => array(
             "test2subtest1" => array(..)
            )
 )
```

So, here is the question: is there any tool in PHP which can be used to assign values to multidimensional array with **random depth** and **index names**? It suppose to look like this:

```
$valuetoassing = "TESTVALUE";
$testarray     = array();
array_assign_multidimensional($testarray, $valuetoassing, array("test1", "test1subtest1", "test1subtest1subtest1"));
```

Problem is that I do not know what depth the array will have, so I can not code it. Index names are also generated at the run time.

EDIT: I figured that my particular case can be solved using some kind of *linked list* (stored as array with items that contain actual data and pointer to the index of the next element), but I'm sure I'll meet this problem again in the future so I will not close the question right now.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do using [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php).

```
function array_assign_multidimensional(&$input_array, $value, $list){
        $assignee = &$input_array;
        foreach($list as $key){
                $assignee = &$assignee[$key];
        }
        $assignee = $value;
}


$input = array(
        'firstLayer' => array(
                'secondLayer' => array(
                        'test' => 'old'
                )
        ),
        'randomOutlyingValue' => ''
);

array_assign_multidimensional($input, 'new', array('firstLayer', 'secondLayer', 'test'));

var_dump($input);

/*
array(2) {
  ["firstLayer"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["secondLayer"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["test"]=>
      string(3) "new"
    }
  }
  ["randomOutlyingValue"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
*/
```